# How to get file icon using C++

Tags: c++, windows, icons

I want to add Icon to treeview node, using C++. I want to get the icons from system, I tried

I tried with,

```
PMString ucPath("C:\\path\\to\\file.extension");
SHFILEINFO info;    

::SHGetFileInfo(ucPath.GrabTString(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &info, sizeof(info),
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SMALLICON);

iconView->SetRsrcID((RsrcID) info.hIcon);
::DestroyIcon(info.hIcon);
```

where, SetResrcID ,PMString are the InDesing API and iconView is the controlView of the Tree, I am not getting what's going wrong, if anyone has idea please suggest.

Thanks,
Praveen Mamdge

Answer (score 2):

Here is the codes what I'm using in my application, you should change the icon to a bitmap.

```
PMString ucPath("C:\\path\\to\\file.extension");
SHFILEINFO info;    

::SHGetFileInfo(ucPath.GrabTString(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &info, sizeof(info),
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
ICONINFO stIconInfo;
GetIconInfo(s_sfi.hIcon, &stIconInfo);
HBITMAP hBmp = stIconInfo.hbmColor;
DestroyIcon(s_sfi.hIcon) ;
```

The best way to do it is using the system icon index with SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this,
Extract icon from file first.

```
SHFILEINFO stFileInfo;
SHGetFileInfo( file,
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
               &stFileInfo,
               sizeof( stFileInfo ),
               SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON );
```

Then add to imagelist and use the index to set icon.

```
m_nIndex = m_ilLargeIcons.Add( stFileInfo.hIcon );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code snippet, observe line by line:

> PMString ucPath("C:\path\to\file.extension"); SHFILEINFO info;
>    ::SHGetFileInfo(ucPath.GrabTString(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &info, sizeof(info),
>       SHGFI_ICON |
>        SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
>
> iconView->SetRsrcID((RsrcID) info.hIcon);
>
> ::DestroyIcon(info.hIcon);

After this line: `iconView->SetRsrcID((RsrcID) info.hIcon);`, you called ::DestroyIcon that destroyed that icon you stored.